# Powershell XNOR of parameter switches

Tags: powershell

The following switch arguments are partially required. At least one of the following is required, but both of the paired arguments are required if either of them are declared:

- VS and PS
- HS and DS
- GS
- CS

I have a verification function that converts the switches to `bool` data types and then uses complicated boolean algebra to check, but I'd like to make it cleaner and compile-time checked.

Is this enforceable with parameter sets?

Command-line arguments parameter list

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$HlslScript,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$vs,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$hs,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$ds,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$gs,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$ps,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$cs
)
```

Verification function

```
function Verify-Args {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [bool]$vs,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [bool]$hs,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [bool]$ds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [bool]$gs,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [bool]$ps,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [bool]$cs
    )
    $nostages = $false -eq ($vs -or $hs -or $ds -or $gs -or $ps -or $cs)
    if(!$nostages) {
        $vsps = !(!$vs -or !$ps) -and !($vs -xor $ps)
        $hsds = !(!$hs -or !$ds) -and !($hs -xor $ds)
        $invalid = -not ($vsps -or $hsds -or $gs -or $cs)
        if($invalid) {
            Write-Host "Missing required arguments. VS and PS, HS and DS, or GS, or CS"
            Return $false
        }
        Return $true
    } else {
        Write-Host "No shader stages specified."
        Return $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Parameter Sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets?view=powershell-7#multiple-parameter-sets)s are the way to go:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$OutputPath,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'VSPS' )]
    [Switch]$vs,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'VSPS' )]
    [Switch]$ps,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'HSDS' )]
    [Switch]$hs,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'HSDS' )]
    [Switch]$ds,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'GS' )]
    [Switch]$gs,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'CS' )]
    [Switch]$cs
)
```

---

### Edit: Per this comment:

> Please clarify: As @SimonS points out in his answer, would I be able
> to use more than one set? It is conceivable for, say, a particle
> system shader to use `-vs -ps -gs` to generate quads from points; or, a
> visual mandelbrot set generated with `-vs -ps -cs`; or an animated tile
> mesh to be generated on the GPU via tesselation: `-vs -ps -hs -ds -cs`
> – Casey

The code above defines four parameter sets that, as written, are rather strict and the switch combinations:

- -vs -ps -gs
- -vs -ps -cs
- -vs -ps -hs -ds -cs

will all generate errors. To make `-gs` and `-cs`  available as optional switches to other parameter sets, add additonal parameter attributes that specify the `ParameterSetName` but omit `Mandetory`. This code allows all the requested combinations:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter( Mandatory , Position = 0 )]
    [string]$OutputPath,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'VSPS')]
    [Switch]$vs,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'VSPS' )]
    [Switch]$ps,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'HSDS' )]
    [Parameter( ParameterSetName = 'VSPS')]
    [Switch]$hs,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'HSDS' )]
    [Parameter( ParameterSetName = 'VSPS')]
    [Switch]$ds,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'GS' )]
    [Parameter( ParameterSetName = 'VSPS')]
    [Parameter( ParameterSetName = 'HSDS')]
    [Switch]$gs,
    [Parameter( Mandatory , ParameterSetName = 'CS' )]
    [Parameter( ParameterSetName = 'VSPS')]
    [Parameter( ParameterSetName = 'HSDS')]
    [Switch]$cs
)
```

Comment: That's the exact same thing that I have as the second point of my answer, with the same limitations as I described.

Comment: Please clarify: As @SimonS points out in his answer, would I be able to use more than one set? It is conceivable for, say, a particle system shader to use `-vs -ps -gs`  to generate quads from points; or, a visual mandelbrot set generated with `-vs -ps -cs`; or an animated tile mesh to be generated on the GPU via tesselation: `-vs -ps -hs -ds -cs`

Comment: @SimonS. Yes. Your answer wasn't there when I began composing my reply. And vice-versa.

Comment: @Casey: Your original question seemed to imply the sets were mutually exculsive and my code reflects that assumption. Did you read the linked documentation? You can only use one parameter set at a time, each paramter set must have at least one value unique to it, but the same value can appear in multiple parameter sets. I will edit my answer to provide examples.

Comment: The new parameter set will work for my purposes. It still fails if you forget one of the required parameters, even if you supply it in the "Please supply a value" message due to conversion failures; but, the help message I wrote clearly states you must supply both.